# Book recommendation to prepare for geometry in the International Mathematical Olympiad

Tags: contest-math, book-recommendation

What is the best book for preparation for "Geometry" for IMO?

I've been searching one for past many weeks, got loads of names but couldn't finalize one, please help me.

Comment: I don't think it's about getting a specific book, I think its about getting enough practice

Answer (score 3):

[106 Geometry Problems from the AwesomeMath Summer Program](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979926947)

[103 Trigonometry Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817643346)

---

You can also check out actual olympiad problems at [mathlinks](http://mathlinks.ro) and at [brilliant](https://brilliant.org/)